# Do I need to trigger an event for the bind with Combox works properly?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have an issue with a ComboBox

```
    private void Form_AddGoal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        LoadGoal();
        IList<Perspective> perspectives = PerspectiveRepository.All(); // I get all perspectives

        CBPerspective.DataSource = perspectives;
        CBPerspective.DisplayMember = "Name";

        // Here I initialize other components
    }

    private void LoadGoal()
    {
        if (Goal== null)
            Goal = new Goal();

        // Here I bind other components

        CBPerspective.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", Goal, "Perspective");   
    }

    public void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          // I save the Goal
    }
```

When the form is open, all is ok. If I don't choose any option in the combobox (That is, the first option keep it) and I save the data on the form the Perspective property is null but If I choose other option in the combobox and proceed in the same way, perspective is equal to the selected item so works perfectly.
What is going on? Do I need trigger an event?

Comment: It seems like a bug in the ComboBox (or WinForms binding system, which actually has a lot of bugs!). I'll investigate it farther when found some time.

Comment: Have you tried setting the selectedIndex to -1 to force the user to select an item?  It's not the best way, but it should work and force the user to select something.  Also, if you want that to return the item that the user hasn't selected yet (the first one), set the selected index to 0.

Comment: Thank you @MD.Unicorn I apreciate your interest!

Comment: @justderb setting the `SelectedIndex` to -1 and force the user it isn't the best way as you say but at least it is a solution, thank you!